# Road API for android native

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-roads-api

is there any APIs in android native to use Road Map APIs to fetch smooth direction route. i found in google map JavaScript [Google map road apis](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) but not sure about the Google Map Library for android

Answer (score 1):

There is not. There is a [Roads API client library in Java](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) and although it's not technically supported on Android, it should work. The reason it's not supported is that it requires you to distribute your API key with your app, which is not considered secure. If your use case has restricted distribution (e.g. it's a purely internal app), this may not be an issue for you.